# Axios get inside a .then is not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios to make a http request. Inside the .then() i am using another axios call. Finally, I have a third then() which is supposed to run after the second then but it is actually not doing so.

```
let assets = [];

export const initAssets = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLoadingToTrue());
        axios.get('https://....json')
            .then(response => {
                for(let key in response.data) {
                    assets.push(response.data[key]);
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                const token = '...';
                assets.forEach((cur) => {
                    axios.get('...' + cur.ticker + '/quote?token=' + token)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        cur.price = response.data.latestPrice;
                    })                    
                })                
            })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(initAllAssets(assets));
                dispatch(setLoadingToFalse());
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                dispatch(setLoadingToFalse());
            })
    }
}
```

The dispatch on the last .then are being executed before the axios request in the second then is completed. How can I make the last then run only after the second axios request is completed?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `Promise.all` to return the response to next .then block and it will be called once all the promises have resolved in the second `.then`

```
let assets = [];

export const initAssets = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLoadingToTrue());
        axios.get('https://....json')
            .then(response => {
                for(let key in response.data) {
                    assets.push(response.data[key]);
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                const token = '...';
                const promises = [];
                assets.forEach((cur) => {
                    promises.push(axios.get('...' + cur.ticker + '/quote?token=' + token)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        cur.price = response.data.latestPrice;
                    }))                   
                }) 
                return Promise.all(promises);               
            })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(initAllAssets(assets));
                dispatch(setLoadingToFalse());
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                dispatch(setLoadingToFalse());
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. Still, I was trying to work with promise.all, but I can't see how to make it work in my situation. In my case, the second axios call http depends on the response for the first call. They cannot run simultaneously. The third .then is should be executed once the second is completed. Can you provide me with further detail on how you would make this work with promise.all? thanks